# Use of unresolved identifier

Tags: ios, swift

I have create a function with return type BOOL  and when I try to return yes/no it gives me error Use of unresolved identifier YES

```
func greet(one:String) -> Bool
{
    return yes
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in Swift, Bool types are `true` and `false`. Not `YES` and `NO`

Comment: This is covered in the "[The Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)" chapter of the Swift book. Might be worth a read if you've not got that far yet.

Answer (score 4):

Swift Bools use true and false

```
func greet(one:String) -> Bool
{
    return true
}
```

If you really miss the Objective-C syntax, you can set YES and NO to be constants.

```
let YES = true
let NO = false
func greet(one:String) -> Bool
{
    return YES
}
```

Comment: Also: typealias BOOL = Bool ;-)

Comment: Yes, you *can* set YES and NO constants, but *should* you? If you're using a new language, you should adapt to the new syntax, not try to mold it into a different language.